# Labelling a pandas dataframe based on data in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to label a pandas dataframe with labels 0,1,2 etc.

Code I am trying is

```
import pandas as pd
# initialise data of lists.
data = {'Path':['/content/gdrive/MyDrive/DOA_dataset/theta_30/s1', '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/DOA_dataset/theta_30/s2', '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/DOA_dataset/theta_60/s1','/content/gdrive/MyDrive/DOA_dataset/theta_60/s2',
                '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/DOA_dataset/theta_90/s1','/content/gdrive/MyDrive/DOA_dataset/theta_90/s2']}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Expected Output**

```
                                   Path                             Label
0   /content/gdrive/MyDrive/DOA_dataset/theta_30/s1                  0
1   /content/gdrive/MyDrive/DOA_dataset/theta_30/s2                  0
2   /content/gdrive/MyDrive/DOA_dataset/theta_60/s1                  1
3   /content/gdrive/MyDrive/DOA_dataset/theta_60/s2                  1
4   /content/gdrive/MyDrive/DOA_dataset/theta_90/s1                  2
5   /content/gdrive/MyDrive/DOA_dataset/theta_90/s2                  2
```

I tried several ways like based on re pattern etc. But none was a success... Any help.

Comment: What is the label based on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `split` then `factorize`

```
df['new'] = df.Path.str.rsplit('/',n=1).str[0].factorize()[0]
df
                                              Path  new
0  /content/gdrive/MyDrive/DOA_dataset/theta_30/s1    0
1  /content/gdrive/MyDrive/DOA_dataset/theta_30/s2    0
2  /content/gdrive/MyDrive/DOA_dataset/theta_60/s1    1
3  /content/gdrive/MyDrive/DOA_dataset/theta_60/s2    1
4  /content/gdrive/MyDrive/DOA_dataset/theta_90/s1    2
5  /content/gdrive/MyDrive/DOA_dataset/theta_90/s2    2
```